# How to set ajaxtoolkit:FileUpload Control's Upload button as a target Id of ajaxtoolkit:ModalPopUpExtender?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hello guys I am uploading [image] files using ajaxtoolkit:FileUpload Control. Now when I click Upload button I just save the [image] file in a folder. What I want to do after that is I want to save the file in DB, but before saving I want to get the [image]files just saved and Add some more information with that file say Image Description, Title etc., and then save it to Database. So I am doing it with Modalpopup Extender. So to display Modal popup extender I need to set the target id of that Extender to the Browse button of FileUpload Control. But I am not getting how exactly I can do this. Is it really possible to do this way. Hope will get some ultimate solutions.

```
     <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload style="position:absolute; width:695px; overflow:auto;max-height:600px"  MaximumNumberOfFiles="7" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png,gif"  
            id="ajaxUpload1"  OnUploadComplete="ajaxUpload1_UploadComplete" runat="server" Width="633px"/>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

    <ajaxtoolkit:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
cancelcontrolid="btnCancel" targetcontrolid="???"
popupcontrolid="Panel1" 
drag="false" backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG" oncancelscript="ClearUI();"
behaviorid="modalwithinput"> </ajaxtoolkit:modalpopupextender>


<asp:panel id="Panel1" style="display: none" runat="server">
<div class="HellowWorldPopup">
            <div class="PopupHeader" id="PopupHeader"><h3 style="color:white; font-family:'Palatino Linotype'">Edit Image</h3></div>
            <div class="PopupBody"  id="ppbody" runat="server">

    </div>
```

Comment: How does the AjaxFileUpload render in HTML when you run the page?  That could give you an idea of how to do it with jQuery, but I don't think it's possible with pure ASP.NET.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely.. there any example that you can provide with for me???

Comment: Attach the rendered HTML for your page and I'll whip something up.